# What does related or dependent mean here?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, abstract-factory

In `Elements of Reusable Object Oriented software` by Erich Gamma and friends, the intent for `Abstract Factory Pattern` says:

> Provide an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes.

Can anyone explain in clearer terms what does author mean by `related or dependent` here.

Comment: I hardly understand what was the need to downvote this question. If somebody downvotes he/she must specify the reason for doing that as well.

Comment: Don't mind, my question was -5ed and deleted. Strong moderation, nothing new...

Comment: To be honest, I'd be more worried about 'families' - when was the last time you saw an abstract factory in the wild that created 'families' rather than single instances?

Comment: It means one of the objects knows about the other. Or that some object knows about them both.

Comment: See: [Discuss this ${blog}](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6417). Asking us to explain what precisely an author of a book or blog meant is generally off topic, as any answer would be speculation. This isn't quite the case here because you are asking about a fairly well established concept. However, the question is currently rather broad because you have not explained your current understanding: what do you think a family of related classes would be? Consider an [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @JotWaraich I appreciate you being willing to clarify. But we greatly prefer you do it by editing the question. Answering a question should not require reading through it's comments.

Comment: It has no special meaning, this is just the normal standard English meaning of those words.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah obviously these are English words but can mean different things in different context. You can say it after being in the industry for a decade but you might not say it when you are new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia says that "The abstract factory pattern provides a way to encapsulate a group of individual factories that have a common theme without specifying their concrete classes."

Take a look at the picture below.

[image]

"Related" here means that all of the concrete factories create *buttons.*

Comment: "Families" also implies that there are other related things, continuing the GUI example, there could also be `TextEdit` and `Frame` interfaces with `WinTextEdit` and `OSXFrame` etc concrete classes

Comment: @Caleth: Indeed.  Part of the problem with vocabulary questions like this one is that it's tricky to know the right scope of information to provide in an answer.  While the community prefers comprehensive answers, really it is just a question about a word.   Full understanding of a pattern like this requires more than just knowing a word.